# how can i log rotation my log file with cron job

Tags: linux, cron, apigee, logrotate

I have logs file like `edge-message-processor.log`
[image: Log image]

and I want as soon as this file size is reach at 10MB then it will rotate my log to new directory.

Comment: Just use logrotate

Comment: @RamanSailopal can you please guide me how can i do this

Comment: man logrotate...